# Error 503 after trying upload file

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, cpanel, http-status-code-503

I'm using laravel and I have a form with two file fields, try to upload a file with 70mb but takes long and after returns an error 503 unavailable service.

I thought that was because php configuration, so I access to cpanel and change the `upload_max_filesize` to `256mb` but it doesn't work yet.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: please share code

Comment: Do you restart your server after doing that?

Comment: How can I restart the server? It's in cpanel hosting @MahfuzShishir

Comment: Could it be because the maximum_exacution_timeout? It is set with 60 seconds, but to upload 70mb takes more than 1minute ...@MahfuzShishir

Comment: does it work on your local machine?

Comment: Yes. And if I upload file with less mb works... @DhavalChheda

Comment: Before everything (stop trying to guess the problem) get the error logs (from laravel, from php and from apache/nginx) there will probably be the explanation for the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
post_max_size = 1024M 
upload_max_filesize = 1024M 
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 3600 
memory_limit = 1024M
```

edit those setting in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You’re going to need to go find your nginx configuration files.
/etc/nginx/sites-available/

Then edit the configuration file and add this :

```
server{

client_max_body_size 5M; //add this line into server section

}
```